# Implicit polymorphism vs Explicit polymorphism in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphism

I have read the O/R Mapping of `Hibernate` and I just can't seem to get past the part on `polymorphism`.
According to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html,

> Implicit polymorphisms means that instances of the class will be
> returned by a query that names any superclass or implemented interface
> or class, and that instances of any subclass of the class will be
> returned by a query that names the class itself

**whereas**

> Explicit polymorphisms means that class instances will be returned
> only by queries that explicitly name that class. Queries that name the
> class will return only instances of subclasses mapped

I just want to understand how these 2 work. Can somebody explain these terms using an example(doesn't have to be too complex) with the use of code? I would appreciate your help

Comment: anybody can show examples of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` annotation is [deprecated](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/annotations/Entity.java#L20) now. You should use the [@Polymorphism](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-polymorphism) annotation instead.

Now, imagine that you have the following schema:

```sql
create table TST_STUDENT
(
   st_id int not null,
   st_name varchar(200),
   
   primary key (st_id)
);
insert into TST_STUDENT values (1, 'Kostya'), (2, 'Yulia'), (3, 'Borya'), (4, 'Misha');

create table TST_TEACHER
(
   tcr_id int not null,
   tcr_first_name varchar(200),
   tcr_last_name varchar(200),
   
   primary key (tcr_id)
);
insert into TST_TEACHER values (1, 'Mikhail', 'Bulgakov'), (2, 'Leo', 'Tolstoy');
```

and the following mapping:

```java
public interface Person
{
   Long getId();
   
   String getName();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TST_STUDENT")
public class Student implements Person
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "st_id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "st_name")
   private String name;
   
   public Student()
   {
   }
   
   // getters / setters
}
```

and `Teacher` entity:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Polymorphism;
import org.hibernate.annotations.PolymorphismType;


@Entity
@Table(name = "TST_TEACHER")
// @Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class Teacher implements Person
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "tcr_id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "tcr_first_name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "tcr_last_name")
   private String lastName;
   
   public Teacher()
   {
   }

   // getters / setters
}
```

Now, if you run the following query:

```java
List<Person> persons = em.createQuery("select p from com.your.entities.Person p", Person.class).getResultList();
```

you will get all rows from the `TST_STUDENT` table plus all rows from the `TST_TEACHER` table.

But, if you uncomment this line:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TST_TEACHER")
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT) // now we use explicit polymorphism for the Teacher entity
public class Teacher implements Person
```

The mentioned above query will return only rows from the `TST_STUDENT` table.
This is what this annotation mean.

By default, when you query a base class entity, the polymorphic query will fetch all subclasses belonging to the base type. *You can even query interfaces or base classes that don’t belong to the JPA entity inheritance model.*

P.S. See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-polymorphism) part of documentation.